# How to call a js function onSelect event of datepicker jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, onselect

Please anyone help me..
I have a js function

```
function updateAb(param){ some manipulation }
```

And i am calling a datepicker jquery onselect event like..

```
$( ".datepicker").datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { ... }});
```

I want to call the js function in select, how to do that? My objective is to get the value onselect of date from the datepicker and setting the attribute value in input field. Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Here goes ur code**

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
         updateAb(selected);
    }
});

function updateAb(value){     
    $('#yourInputID').val(value);    
}
```

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah you are right, i was not clear with my question, but i wanted what Kabilan posted here. Thanks to both of you...

Answer (score 5):

```
$( ".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        updateAb(dateText);
    }
});
```

Even more simply, if you do want the `dateText` and `inst` parameters to be passed to `updateAb`

```
$( ".datepicker").datepicker({onSelect: updateAb});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$( ".datepicker").datepicker({
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          updateAb(dateText, inst);
       }
});
```

In short

```
$( ".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: updateAb
});
```

Comment: Are you updating copying my answer? :p

Comment: @JuanMendes no mate, its not my habit,it happen in parallal

Comment: I didn't think you were actually doing it, just that I kept seeing your updates immediately after my updates

Comment: @JuanMendes so what should I do, mate?